# how to watch the http requested data using postman

Tags: node.js, json, http, postman

i have got the data by making the following http request , currently i am doing console.log() , but how to see the data in postman.

```
function getProducts() {
  http
    .get(url, (res) => {
      let body = "";
      res.on("data", (chunk) => {
        body += chunk;
      });
      res.on("end", () => {
        try {
          let json = JSON.parse(body);
          console.log(json);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error.message);
        }
      });
    })
    .on("error", (error) => {
      console.error(error.message);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`http.get()` does exactly what Postman do.

If you want the data in Postman, just call `url` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand it correctly but here's what I can say

1. Download and install postman from [here](https://www.postman.com/downloads)
2. The UI is simple, it has tabs like browsers, create a new tab(request)
3. Default http method is Get so you don't need to change it. type your URL click Send button.
4. you can add Headers, etc...

[image: The Showcase]